# valid json is not created with regex as a value

Tags: json, regex

I have a valid regex

```
(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+
```

This is available at and can be validated at
https://www.regextester.com/94502

Now I a trying to create a JSON in which the above expression is used as a value.

```
{
    "regex": "^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$"
}
```

This can be verified at
https://jsonlint.com/

It turns out to be a invalid json. What is wrong with the above json?

Answer (score 1):

The quoted string on the right of `"regex":` contains the character sequences

```
    \.  \w  \]  \+   \(   \)
```

and each of these is not valid in a JSON string - See http://json.org/ for a brief and "visual" explanation of the grammar.

To represent the given regex as a valid JSON string, each backslash has to be doubled (i.e. replace `\` by `\\`, much like in other languages like PHP, C/C++ etc.), so the relevant line should become something like

```
  "regex": "^(?:http(s)?:\\/\\/)?[\\w.-]+   ...
```

Comment: The json is fixed when the backslash is doubled( \ is replaced by \\). Special characters are fine. Thanks for pointing in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The special characters need to escape according to the http://www.json.com. And you don't need to espace single-quote `'` but It is a bad practice to use single-quote. For new readers, please use double-quote, It will let you get rid of many headaches.

```
\b  Backspace (ASCII code 08)
\f  Form feed (ASCII code 0C)
\n  Newline
\r  Carriage return
\t  Tab
\"  Double quote
\\  Backslash character
```

**Todo:**

- Change single quote to double quote.
- Apply the Characters given above to escape special characters.

Comment: I guess I didnt understand but the regex does not have backspace, form feed or other characters